# Simple iteration over one object to display it's keys and values

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a object that looks like this:

```
const people = {
  men: 4,
  women: 2,
  total: 6,
  participants: {
    1: 4,
    2: 1,
    3: 0
  }
};
```

I am trying to achieve such result:

1 participants count 4
2 participants count 1 
3 participants count 0 <- Hide me if count === 0

What is the best way to achieve this? using `map` or `forEach` or `for` loop? Any help is appreciated, I have tried:

```
for (let key in people.participants) {
 console.log("count",people.participants[key],"key",key;
}
```

which seems to be working except I cannot use it in React component like i would with `map` ...

Comment: @Jason Brill Do you want to get result like so https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/53439/?

Comment: Oh! Exactly Thank you so much....!!! @AlexanderT.

Answer (score -1):

My favourite way :)

```
people.participants.forEach(function(elem, index, array) {
    if(elem === 0) {
        hideElem(elem);
    }
}, this);

function hideElem(elem) {
    //do the stuff here
}
```